# How to create hover out effect using css3

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to transform my image back to original size after user hover out of my image..Not sure what to do here..

MY css

```
//doesn't work
.imgDiv img{

-webkit-transform:scale(1, 1);
-moz-transform:scale(1, 1);
-o-transform:scale(1, 1);
-ms-transform:scale(1, 1);
transform:scale(1, 1);

}


//enlarge the image but don't know how to shrink them back

.imgDiv:hover img{

-webkit-transform:scale(1.15, 1.15);
-moz-transform:scale(1.15, 1.15);
-o-transform:scale(1.15, 1.15);
-ms-transform:scale(1.15, 1.15);
transform:scale(1.15, 1.15);

}
```

html...

```
<div class='imgDiv'>

     <img src='a.jpg' />
     <img src='b.jpg' />
     <img src='c.jpg' />
     <img src='d.jpg' />

</div>
```

Thanks for the help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove all the `transform` properties from the original declaration. Since the images are, by default, scaled to `1`, you don't need to declare that. Anything that you set in an element's `:hover` pseudo class is reverted to its default when the mouse is removed.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/RCjQd/) is an example.

Here's the final CSS:

```
.imgDiv:hover img{
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.15, 1.15);
    -moz-transform:scale(1.15, 1.15);
    -o-transform:scale(1.15, 1.15);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.15, 1.15);
    transform:scale(1.15, 1.15);
}
```

Of course, if you were trying to apply this to each image, then you'd still remove the `.imgDiv img` declaration and change `.imgDiv:hover img` to `.imgDiv img:hover`.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/RCjQd/1/) is an example of that in action.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `:hover` on your images

```
.imgDiv img:hover{
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.15, 1.15);
       -moz-transform:scale(1.15, 1.15);
        -ms-transform:scale(1.15, 1.15);
         -o-transform:scale(1.15, 1.15);
            transform:scale(1.15, 1.15);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MqJwJ/)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a transition you got a nice transition effect on hover:

```
.imgDiv img:hover{
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.15, 1.15);
    -moz-transform:scale(1.15, 1.15);
    -o-transform:scale(1.15, 1.15);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.15, 1.15);
    transform:scale(1.15, 1.15);
}

.imgDiv img {    
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
​
```